# Translate SQL column result into text

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, if-statement

I have some SQL that selects columns from tables like normal. However, one of my columns (u.cmc_rti_type) is a number and I want it to output text instead. I assume I need some sort of if statement. Here is my sql:

```
    SELECT '', s.student_number, s.lastfirst, s.grade_level, t.TEACHER, u.cmc_rti_tier, u.cmc_rti_type
            FROM students s 
            JOIN u_def_ext_students u
            ON u.studentsdcid = s.dcid
            LEFT JOIN cmc_homeroom_teacher t
            ON s.dcid = t.dcid
            WHERE u.cmc_rti_tier <> 0
            ORDER BY s.lastfirst
```

if u.cmc_rti_type is 1 then I want it to output 'Reading'
if u.cmc_rti_type is 2 then I want it to output 'Math'
if u.cmc_rti_type is 3 then I want it to output 'Enrichment'
if u.cmc_rti_type is 4 then I want it to output 'Both Math & Reading'

Comment: look up how `case` expression works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT '', s.student_number, s.lastfirst, s.grade_level, t.TEACHER,
   u.cmc_rti_tier, 
   CASE u.cmc_rti_type 
      WHEN 1 THEN 'Reading'
      WHEN 2 THEN 'Math'
      WHEN 3 THEN 'Enrichment'
      WHEN 4 THEN 'Both Math & Reading'
      ELSE NULL
   END AS cmc_rti_type 
FROM students s 
JOIN u_def_ext_students u
  ON u.studentsdcid = s.dcid
LEFT JOIN cmc_homeroom_teacher t
  ON s.dcid = t.dcid
WHERE u.cmc_rti_tier <> 0
ORDER BY s.lastfirst
```

Or if you are using **SQL Sever 2012+** you can use `CHOOSE`:

```
CHOOSE(u.cmc_rti_type, 'Reading', 'Math', 'Enrichment', 'Both Math & Reading') AS cmc_rti_type
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382142)**</kbd>

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` in following:

```
SELECT '', s.student_number, s.lastfirst, s.grade_level, t.TEACHER, u.cmc_rti_tier, 
        CASE u.cmc_rti_type WHEN 1 THEN 'Reading'
                            WHEN 2 THEN 'Math'
                            WHEN 3 THEN 'Enrichment'
                            WHEN 4 THEN 'Both Math & Reading'
        END AS Etc
        FROM students s 
        JOIN u_def_ext_students u
        ON u.studentsdcid = s.dcid
        LEFT JOIN cmc_homeroom_teacher t
        ON s.dcid = t.dcid
        WHERE u.cmc_rti_tier <> 0
        ORDER BY s.lastfirst
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `case`:

```
SELECT CASE u.cmc_rti_type 
            WHEN 1 then 'Reading'
            WHEN 2 then 'Math'
            WHEN 3 then 'Enrichment'
            WHEN 4 then 'Both Math & Reading' END, 
       s.student_number, 
       s.lastfirst, 
       s.grade_level, 
       t.TEACHER, 
       u.cmc_rti_tier, 
       u.cmc_rti_type
FROM students s 
JOIN u_def_ext_students u ON u.studentsdcid = s.dcid
LEFT JOIN cmc_homeroom_teacher t ON s.dcid = t.dcid
WHERE u.cmc_rti_tier <> 0
ORDER BY s.lastfirst
```

Answer (score 1):

And, for something completely different.

If you have the necessary permissions, a lookup table could be used to do the work of the case statement. This would let you add more choices in the future without having to find all the code that does this case statement.

```
CREATE TABLE rti_type_lookup
(
 rti_type_value int not null,
 rti_type_label varchar(100) not null
)

INSERT INTO rti_type_lookup (rti_type_value, rti_type_label)
VALUES (1, 'Reading'),
       (2, 'Math'),
       (3, 'Enrichment'),
       (4, 'Both Math & Reading')
```

Now, when you need to get the text version, you can do a JOIN. And, in the future, you can just add new lookup values in the `rti_type_lookup` table instead of updating your `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT '', s.student_number, s.lastfirst, s.grade_level, t.TEACHER,
   u.cmc_rti_tier, rti_type_label AS cmc_rti_type 
FROM students s 
JOIN u_def_ext_students u
  ON u.studentsdcid = s.dcid
JOIN rti_type_lookup l
  ON u.cmc_rti_type = l.rti_type_value
LEFT JOIN cmc_homeroom_teacher t
  ON s.dcid = t.dcid
WHERE u.cmc_rti_tier <> 0
ORDER BY s.lastfirst
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks for the info!